# Can a Webform display the last submitted version of instead of creating a new submission

Tags: webforms

I have a web form that is embedded into a field on a content type and wondering if the form has been already submitted can you display the webform/manage/webform_name/submission/webforn_numer/edit form instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!!! Just go to Webform: Submissions: Settings and check off 'Limit total to one submission' per user or per submission.

[image]